# Does FogBugz offer an API for managing User Groups?

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

Fog Bugs [User Groups](http://help.fogcreek.com/7606/fogbugz-user-groups) are described in their help articles, but the FogBugz [API Documentation](http://help.fogcreek.com/8202/xml-api) does not mention a method for interacting with them.

How can I add and remove users from a FogBugz UserGroup programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From FogBugz Support:

> There currently isn’t any support for modifying User Group membership
>   using either our published XML API or our unpublished (in progress)
>   JSON API.  We do have an outstanding issue to add access to User
>   Groups via the API, and I’ll add your vote to that case.